# Download images on client to zip

Tags: javascript, angularjs, download, jszip, downloadify

Okey, so what I want to do is download multiple images stored in an JavaScript array in AngularJS. I have not found any way of doing this in the form of "pure" images like .png .jpg etc (although if anyone knows how to do this please let me know). So I have turned to trying to zip the images with the help of jszip.js according to the description here : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-zip-file-javascript/

```
<li ng-click="download()"><a>Save to harddrive</a></li>
```

So this is the code called when the user clicks "download":

```
photodice.controller('ProjectController', function($scope, imageFactory) {
$scope.images = imageFactory.getImages();
$scope.download = function() {
   var zip = new JSZip();
   for (var x in $scope.images) {
      zip.folder("images").add("image" + x + ".png", $scope.images[x], {base64: true});
   }
   var content = zip.generate();
   console.log("content = "+ content);
   location.href="data:application/zip;base64," + content;
}
});
```

The problems occurs when the last line of code is executed, the browser crashes... I do not really understand how filedownloads work... Any suggestion or tips on what I should read up on would be greatly appreciated!

Update:
I tried using Downloadify to solve my problem... and added some code:

```
$scope.download = function() {
var zip = new JSZip();
for (var x in $scope.images) {
    zip.folder("images").add("image" + x + ".jpg", $scope.images[x], {base64: true});
}
Downloadify.create('downloadify',{
  filename: function(){
    return "Images.zip";
},
  data: function(){
    return zip.generate();
},    
  onComplete: function(){ 
    alert('Your File Has Been Saved!'); 
},
  onCancel: function(){ 
    alert('You have cancelled the saving of this file.');
},
  onError: function(){ 
    alert('You must put something in the File Contents or there will be nothing to save!'); 
},
transparent: false,
swf: 'downloadify.swf',
downloadImage: 'img/download.png',
width: 100,
height: 30,
transparent: true,
append: false,
dataType: 'base64'
});
```

And now I can save the zip file:)

HOWEVER I still have a problem... the files in the zip are corrupt...

Normal non corrupt images  look like this:

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAhE... ...c8+ocAAAAORK5CYII="
```

If I upload "currupt" images to my site agian and check the scope of the images that are corrupt the data looks like this:

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,dataimage/jpegbase64iVBORw0KA... ...RNgAK5CYII="
```

Alternatively I remove the {base64: true}:

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,ZGF0YTppbWF... ...WT1JLNUNZSUk9" (no "=" at the end)
```

What can I do about this?

Comment: If you don't need to support IE 6-9, you can use FileSaver.js and a blob, see http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/write_zip.html

Comment: If I understand correctly, inside `$scope.images[x]` you have a string `"data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgo..."`. Am I right ? In that case, you should try removing the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` part (and just keep the base64 content).

Comment: I thought about that... firstly, how would i go about doing that? secoundly, wouldent it make more sence to remove the "dataimage/jpegbase64" part? considering that files with "image/jpeg;base64," appear to work... although i do not know where this is generated...  probebly somewhere in JSZip... but I could not find where...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong : you put "data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw..." in JSZip, generate it, reload this file and you get a strange "dataimage/jpegbase64". I think that the initial "data:image/jpeg;base64," is interpreted as base64 content and corrupt your result. You can try with the following (single line because of stackoverflow comments) : `var base64AndMore = $scope.images[x]; var index = base64.indexOf(","); var justBase64 = base64AndMore.substring(index + 1, base64AndMore.length); zip.folder("images").file("image" + x + ".jpg", $scope.images[x], {base64: true});`

Comment: interesting, why .file insted of add? (will try)

Comment: `add` ? Oh. Are you using an old version ? The `add` method has been deleted in 2011 :D

Comment: Nice! it worked! thank you! you rock! (.file did not work, but i assume that was just a mistake:))

Comment: well then I suppose i use the old version:P should i update?:O

Comment: (im new to stackOverflow... but shouldent you write your awnser in a "real" awnser insted of comments so i can mark it as solved and give you credit?:))

Comment: You should, but that may need some work : only `folder()` and `remove()` haven't changed between your version and the latest. Anyway, I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm putting the answer here for future reference (because it was buried in the comments).

The issue comes from `$scope.images[x]` which contains a string, `"data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAhE... ...c8+ocAAAAORK5CYII="`.  JSZip interprets the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` part as base64 content and generates corrupted images. To remove this part, you can do the following :

```
var base64 = $scope.images[x];
var index = base64.indexOf(",");
if (index !== -1) {
    base64 = base64.substring(index + 1, base64.length);
}
zip.folder("images").file("image" + x + ".jpg", base64, {base64: true});
```

Also, the `add()` method you use has been deleted in 2011 so you may want to update JSZip ! (but that may need some work : only `folder()` and `remove()` haven't changed between your version and the latest).

Comment: I did update to the latest version, and it worked without a hitch:) (only had to change .add to .file) Thanks again!